# Errors after installing Steam - Kubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dependencies, steam

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with KDE Plasma 5.24.6

I downloaded steam_latest.deb from Steam's official site. I installed it via the software installer in Ubuntu, after which I was prompted to download some packages

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages:
libc6:amd64 libc6:i386 libegl1:amd64 libegl1:i386 libgbm1:amd64 libgbm1:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1:amd64 libgl1:i386 steam-libs-i386:i386
```

after continuing I get this output

````
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libegl1 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
libgl1 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
libegl1:i386 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
libgl1:i386 is already the newest version (1.4.0-1).
libc6 is already the newest version (2.35-0ubuntu3.1).
libc6:i386 is already the newest version (2.35-0ubuntu3.1).
libgbm1 is already the newest version (22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1).
libgbm1:i386 is already the newest version (22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1).
libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 is already the newest version (22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1).
steam-libs-i386:i386 is already the newest version (1:1.0.0.75).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgl1-amber-dri libllvm13
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgl1-mesa-dri
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,887 kB of archives.
After this operation, 374 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 206760 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-dri_22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1) over (22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so', which is also in package libgl1-amber-dri:amd64 21.3.7-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)```
````

and now upon using any apt command I am met with these dependencies errors

```
sudo apt install pythonpy
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1) but 22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1 is to be installed
                   Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1) but 22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1 is to be installed
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Breaks: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1) but 22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I get this output after using sudo apt --fix-broken install

```
googboog@googboog-desktop:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
[sudo] password for googboog: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgl1-amber-dri libllvm13
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgl1-mesa-dri
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgl1-mesa-dri
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,887 kB of archives.
After this operation, 374 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 206760 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-dri_22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1) over (22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so', which is also in package libgl1-amber-dri:amd64 21.3.7-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

**Fixes I've Tried:**

Running sudo apt install -f

```
googboog@googboog-desktop:~$ sudo apt install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgl1-amber-dri libllvm13
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgl1-mesa-dri
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libgl1-mesa-dri
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/7,887 kB of archives.
After this operation, 374 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 206760 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libgl1-mesa-dri_22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1) over (22.0.5-0ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i915_dri.so', which is also in package libgl1-amber-dri:amd64 21.3.7-0ubuntu1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgl1-mesa-dri_22.2.0~rc3+git2208312110.f44745add97~j~mesarc1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Apologies if I am missing any crucial information, I am new to this.

Comment: Steam is in Ubuntu repositories. There's no need to install from any other source and doing so can cause problems when you take things into your own hands and you're not sure what you're doing. I suggest that you undo what you did (if you can) and install steam from repositories.

Comment: @Nmath I've tried to uninstall it aswell but also can't figure that out, I've tried using apt remove but doesn't seem to be working

Comment: You need to know what you did in order to know how to undo it, but none of those details are in your question. Can you edit your question and tell us, in exact terms, what you downloaded, how you installed it, and a complete description of all commands/actions you've taken to get to this point?

Comment: @Nmath I'm not sure what else I need to add, I downloaded steam_latest.deb from their official site, I installed it via the software installer in Ubuntu and then I did everything I listed in the post. anything I try to remove the steam packages, it just gives the same error as the majority of what I put into the post: `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: For example, what command(s) are you using to uninstall? None of the commands you listed in your question are uninstall commands. You can use `sudo apt remove packagename` or `sudo apt purge packagename` to remove offending packages. Was your system up-to-date and your package manager free of errors *before* you tried to install Steam? If you try to force new software with a `.deb` file you downloaded without making sure your system is compatible or up-to-date, it can put you in what's called "dependency hell". Also, why did you try to install `pythonpy`? There's no explanation for that.

Comment: @Nmath I managed to figure out what the problem was, there was some sort of conflict between libgl1-amber-dri and libl1-mesa-dri, so I removed libgl1-amber-dri with `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq libgl1-amber-dri` and the errors no longer appear. Steams seems to be working fine now aswell.

Comment: Please consider posting the details of your solution as an answer below. Ask Ubuntu's purpose, first and foremost, is to build a library of questions and answers about Ubuntu. In many cases, people are able to answer their own question, and this would be helpful for future visitors if you could describe how you solved your problem.